# wampserver2 orange icon after enabling virtual hosts file (httpd-vhosts.conf)

Tags: wamp, virtual-host

I've had a virtual host setup that has been working fine all along, but out of the blue this morning I noticed that when I started up wampserver the icon remained orange and apache was not working.

My config files as follows:

..\Apache2.2.17\conf\httpd.conf:

```
(...other settings...)
Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf
(...other settings...)
```

..\Apache2.2.17\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf: added following entries a while back:

```
(...other settings...)
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   DocumentRoot C:\wamp\www\site1\
   ServerName site1.local
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   DocumentRoot C:\wamp\www\site2\
   ServerName site2.local
</VirtualHost>
```

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 site1.local
127.0.0.1 site2.local
```

After some trial and error I found that if I disabled this line from httpd.conf the wampserver turns green again after restarting. So it seems that something has gone wrong with my virtual host setup.

```
#Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf
```

There have been no recent changes to my system, though my PC did mysteriously reboot once this morning. Any ideas? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just reinstalling WAMP, and used forward slashes "/", though back slashes did work for me before.